# How to recover corrupted web parts?

Tags: web-part, 2007, sql-server

I have two SharePoint websites

A web part is working on one site but corrupted in second site and it is stored in the database.

When I recover database from first site database then the web part is working fine.

**Anybody know in which table SharePoint storing template for web parts?**

Comment: is it custom webpart or OOTB?

Comment: this is custom webpart and i donot have its template.I am finding the way to recover it from first site.

Comment: Did you try the solution mentioned  by eric?

Comment: Yes i had tried it before. But didnot get any success.

Answer (score 1):

Tinkering around to fix it in the database is not recommended or supported. The old stand by is to navigate to your web part page and add `?contents=1` to the end of the URL. Here you can delete the corrupt web part. Then go back to your web part page and add it back.

You can always try exporting the web part from the site it is working in and importing it into the new site after you delete the corrupted one.